# Remove sandbox solution from SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, custom, sandbox-solution

I am working with Custom Ribbon Item development in SharePoint Online, i have created a custom sandbox solution and deployed on my SharePoint Online site. Once i activated the solution my site has been crashed (Not able to open any page, lists and libraries etc) whenever i hit the URL it just shows the blank white page.

So when i deployed same solution to my on premises environment, there also the same problem occurred. But when i retract the solution from on premise site my local site started working fine.

So i decided to retract the solution from SharePoint Online too, but when i enter the SharePoint Online URL in my Visual studio its shows "Property Invalid" error message

And i am not getting the way how can I delete the solution from the SharePoint Online site to get back my site working. For this I tried following things

- Tried retracting the solution using Visual Studio while doing so got   "Property Invalid" Error while i enter site url
- Deployed the solution on Local and recorded the solution Id and Tried retracting from my SharePoint Online site using following powershell script 
  But powershell shows error too

  ```
  deactivate-solution -username "admin@xyz.onmicrosoft.com" -password "xxxx" -siteurl "https://xyz.sharepoint.com" -solutionid "5BC8D9A8-AE5A-4CF8-8D25-03B239818193" -environment MSO_2013
  ```

and I am stucked now as I cannot move forward in development as my site is not working.

If any one have gone through the same situation and knows the solution please help me out.

Suggestions are most welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this [Deactivate Sandbox Solution with PowerShell in Office 365](http://www.alexpearce.tech/microsoft/office-365/deactivate-sandbox-solution-with-powershell-in-office-365-sharepoint-online/#comment-5091)

Also have a look to this link too, it contains the way to [deactivate solution](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.in/2014/07/upload-sandbox-solutions-to-sharepoint.html)

I am not sure about this as i haven't faced this problem but i guess it can help you.